# How Can I Store Program Settings?

Tags: c#, windows, configuration, storage

I am creating a desktop app that will sit on a PC and occasionally check a web server for updates to various settings.

The program will be using these settings frequently so I would like cache the settings in a file on the PC so it doesn't have to hit the server constantly. There are a lot of settings. I was thinking about storing them in an XML file but I need the file to be unreadable by the PC users.

How should I store the settings on the PC that the program can read and write to but the user cannot read?

EDIT: Sorry guys. The application is being written in C# using .NET 2.0. The application will only run on Windows. It is a console app that will run as a Windows Service.

Comment: Programming language? Operating system? Come on, give us a chance here! :)

Comment: What is the scope? Do you need the settings to be per-machine or per-user?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent the user from viewing or changing the settings?

Comment: I don't want to hear "because the settings contain the super secret password to the server!"

Comment: This is an application for employers. The users willbe employees. The employer will be able to change the settings via a web based interface which will manage all settings across a network of machines. The file on the PC will just be a local cache for that PC.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Is the user able to get admin privileges?

Comment: If this is for a corporate setting, then just store the settings file in the program files directory or the registry where users don't have write access.

Comment: If this is a web application, why aren't the settings simply stored in the Web application, where it's relatively easy to keep them safe? Then, the only setting that would be needed on user PCs would be the user's identity (which is hopefully no big secret to the user).

Comment: @Carl, the user should not be able to get admin privileges. Also this is a PC based application but some of the settings are stored on a web server because the settings can apply to a network of PCs. Plus it is going to be subscription based so there needs to be a bit of control of high level settings.

Comment: All of this is only more reason to store the settings in the Web app and not the server. But OK, back to the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the app is a service then it can run under an account that isn't the user's; then it's easy enough to keep the file hidden from him.

As a Windows app, you have your choice of the Registry or a file or a local database. For files, your choice of a simple properties file or an XML file.

For any of those, your choice of encrypted (just in case) or not.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are targeting the Windows platform, you can either

- use the registry
- use a configuration file
- or use a database

Data can be encrypted in all 3 cases if needed. If you really have lots of settings, the registry is probably not the easiest way to do this. If you have a .net app, look at SQL Server Compact Edition, it is really light-weight, easy to deploy with your app, and does not need a runtime environment.

Answer (score 2):

If it is on the end users machine, sooner or later they can read it.  If the program is running on their local machine, then they can make it do whatever they want.  If this is some sort of a client-server program, you simply can never trust what the client says.

One of the easiest ways to store settings in .Net is to create a class that contains everything you want to keep track of, and then serialize it to and from the disk.  Since this file just acts as a cache, you can probably just use a Binary Formatter, which will make the file only readable to those who know what they are doing.

Be sure to save the settings in a UAC friendly directory like [ApplicationData](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/Getting-user-specific-application-data-directory.html).

Comment: Chris, I like your idea but I will probably still encrypt the data. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you could write the aplication configs in a xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="Test1" value="My value 1" />
        <add key="Test2" value="Another value 2" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your idea for an xml configuration is a good start (the XML DOM is easy to navigated, well known, documented, etc.).

If you don't want the user to be able to read/edit the settings you could keep it in memory but you would lose the data from run to run. You didn't seem to indicate that the app would be restarted though so this may work for you. There is also the option of detecting when the app is shutting down and you can then dump you cache to disk.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of if you store these settings locally, if you load them into memory a user can read them.  If you transfer them across a network it is a pretty simple to scan network packets, even over an encrypted connection there are plenty of tools that will man-in-the-middle your own network connection for you (I've used OpenSTA for that, even though it isn't exactly made for it).  Someone who really, really wants to see what you're using for settings will be able to see them if you're running something on their computer.

Now, having said that, keeping them in XML and just encrypting the file is probably the simplest solution.  Even just compressing the file and changing the extension will keep away people who are merely curious about what settings you have.

Answer (score 1):

Settings are pretty easy in C#.net.  Creating a settings file can be done through the project's property pages (Settings tab).  Then if you really want to, you could pick up the settings file and [encrypt the root xml element either with symmetric or asymmetric keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229746.aspx)

Then, as others have mentioned, keeping the keys and routines to edit the settings out of the user's hands is another problem.  You could send the settings to the server on which the private key exists keeping only the public key on the client for decryption, have the server do the encryption/signing.  Any tampering with the settings on the client you would know because the signature would fail.  So, if you have the settings saved locally, the user couldn't read them without a bit of code and you can only decrypt them to use them; writing/creating would be done by the server.

Answer (score 0):

You are concerned about users reading the file or modifying it?

Regardless - you can encrypt it with a random key and bury the key somewhere in the registry